# On the evening news vs. In the evening news

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, prepositions

Why the word ***news*** takes different prepositions in the following sentences?

Our school was mentioned ***in the news***.

I heard it ***on the evening news***.

Do native speakers say ***in **the evening news*****? If *yes*, are they different in meaning?

Answer (score 2):

**On the news** and **in the news** are equally popular expressions (regardless of whether they are modified by **morning, afternoon, evening or similar**)

Without the modifier, **in the news** more often means **newsworthy / being talked about / a current issue or event**.

**On the news** more often refers to an item that someone heard/observed in a news bulletin.

In many contexts the two expressions are interchangeable.

So it's equally idiomatic to say:

> It was on the evening news
> It was (an item) in the evening news

There is no difference in meaning. It comes down to context and preference.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2019&content=on+the+news%2Cin+the+news&corpus